# I want to convert PDF file data to JSON data using nodejs

Tags: node.js, file-conversion

I want to convert PDF file data in JSON format. I want the output of text in proper JSON format but my code converts normal JSON. what is used for this ? and `npm` library `pdf-parse` no give proper formate and `pdf2json` also.

```
var fs=require('fs');
const pdf = require('pdf-parse');
module.exports.simplePdfUpload= (req, res) => {
    upload(req, res, (err) => {
        let dataBuffer = fs.readFileSync(req.files[0].path);  
        pdf(dataBuffer).then(function(data) {
            res.send({"jsondata":data,})
        })
        .catch(function(error){
        })
    })
}
```

**OUTPUT-**

```
{
    'waters including interstate wetlands; (3) all other waters such as ' +
    'intrastate lakes, rivers, streams (including intermittent \nstreams),  ' +
    'mudflats,  sandflats,  wetlands,  sloughs,  prairie  potholes,  wet  ' +
    'meadows,  playa  lakes,  or  natural  ponds,  etc.,  which  the  use, \n' +
    'degradation, or destruction could affect interstate/ foreign commerce; (4) ' +
    'all impoundments of waters otherwise defined as waters of the U. S., \n(5) ' +
    'tributaries of waters identified in 1 through 4 above; (6) the territorial ' +
    'seas; and (7) wetlands adjacent to waters identified in 1 through 6 \n' +
    'above. Only the USACE has the authority to make a final wetlands ' +
    'jurisdictional determination. \n ',
    version: '1.10.100'
}
```

**But I want to output this type**

```
{
    "Info":
    {
        "Company": "ABC",
        "Team": "node"
    },
    "Number of members": 4,
    "Time to finish": "1 day"
}
```

Comment: Where do those information come from ? What does `company`,`Team` and `number of members` refer to in the original text ?

Comment: in pdf data if heading then use as a key ex. {heading : { "subHeading":"somthing.......",
"subHeading":"somthing......."
}
"heading": "somthing.....",
"heading": "somthing....."'

Comment: So, you actually want the structure of the PDF to be parsed, instead of line-by-line, is that it ?

Comment: yes sir according to main Heading and inside sub heading

Comment: '1.0': {
    name: 'INTRODUCTION1',
    sub: [
      '1.1': 'Purpose1',
      '1.2': 'Scope-of-Services1',
      '1.3': 'Standard of Care2',
      '1.4': 'Assumptions2',
      '1.5': 'Limitations and Exceptions4',
      '1.6': 'Special Terms and Conditions4',
      '1.7': 'User Reliance4'
    ]
  },
]

Comment: You might want to edit your question to reflect that. As it is, there is no way I would have understood you wanted to parse the structure instead of the text, and it might be the case of many other users.

Answer (score 0):

pdf-parse provide pdf to text only you need to use other library for it.

pdf.js-extract

Comment: Can you provide any example @Gajanand Pandey